# Javascript not loading on website with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm making a website using python with the flask framework and I can't seem to get my javascript page to work with the html the same way I did with my external css file. I'm not sure where the error is occurring, whether it's in my html head (below) where i'm linking the javascript, in the javascript file or in the python file.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/HotelStyle.css">
 <title> Hotel </title> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="../static/hotel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: If you're using Flask, it's generally best to use url_for to get the URL for static resources. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: Thanks, I tried what the link said and it still didn't work, could it be to do with the javascript file itself?

Answer (score 0):

if you've defined your static directory correctly for *flask* you should be able to use the correct url for your static files by using `url_for`. for example in this case it will be:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='HotelStyle.css') }}">
<title> Hotel </title> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='hotel.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```